# Invalid column name .Don't Know Why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, client-server, stack-trace

**Recently i add DateofBirth to a table . And Locally it's work fine.
I also update client's data base and entity data model. But errors appears.**

Invalid column name 'DateofBirth'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'DateofBirth'.

Stack Trace:

[SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'DateofBirth'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +3305692
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +736
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4061
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +90
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +99
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted) +604
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) +3303
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) +667
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +83
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +301
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +104
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +499
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +36

[EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +125
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute(ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues) +1014
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +459
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5() +203
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +234
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +354
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0() +30
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +39
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +436
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +70
   BLAST.Controllers.EmployeeVarityReportController.EmpDetails() +5302
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +87
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +229
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +77
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f() +387
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f() +387
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c() +38
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +188
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +602
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +195
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +128

Answer (score 3):

The column does not exist in the table, you must run migrations or use other means to update the customer database

Answer (score 1):

Based on the stack trace, I suspect that you have set the **AutomaticMigrationsEnabled** to **false** in the configuration class. To fix this you need to manually create a new migration file. you can create new migration running the **Add-Migration** command in the Nuget Package Manager Console.

[Here is a tutorial on how to create a new migration script.](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-based-migration-in-code-first.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I get this kind of error when I update my table in database but not in the data binding or mapping in my interface yet. After refreshing my data source in my data binding level then all went good. So I guess this error is caused by data sync/update on database level and interfacing level. So, what I must do is to check all the field control-column table mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your query has proper quotations.
For example,

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into student(id,name,dob) values("+id+","+name+","+dob+")";
```

is an exception bound way of writing a query.
Try it in this way

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into student(id,name,dob) values('"+id+"','"+name+"','"+dob+"')";
```

Comment: How is this related to an invalid column name?